# How to extract JSON list values from a Flask GET request?

Tags: python, flask, get

I'm using a `Flask` app which sends a get request to an `ExpressJS` app running in `Kubernetes`. I'm having trouble extracting the list of strings that it receives:

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
    #latestList = requests.get('http://localhost:8085/url1').json()
    latestList = requests.get('http://express:8085/url1').json()
    request_data = []
    for i in latestList:
        request_data.append(i)
    return render_template('index.html', list_of_names = request_data)
```

This is the function of the `ExpressJS` app:

```
app.get('/url1', (req, res) => {
    latestList = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
    //res.send(latestList);
    res.json(latestList);
});
```

What is the right way to extract the list of strings in the Flask app? I got a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `latestList` had to be in a `dict` format. Changes in the Node app:

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
    latestList = requests.get('http://express:8085/url1').json()
    #latestList = requests.get('http://localhost:8085/url1').json()
    request_data = []
    for i in latestList:
        print(i)
        request_data.append(latestList[i])
    return render_template('index.html', list_of_places = request_data)
```

In the ExpressJS app:

```
const app = express();
app.get('/url1', (req, res) => {
    var latestList = {1:"name1", 2:"name2", 3:"name3"}
    res.json(latestList);
});
```